# Displaying Dates as only day of a particular month or day/month using ggplot2?

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, label, as.date

Trying to display dates across the x-axis displaying only day/month or just the days of the month (Aug)(date range: from 31/07/2018 to 31/08/2018). I can run code using as.date function on the "date" column in addition to scale_x_date breaks and the format of the labels but despite no errors, this results in no labels on the x-axis just black lines and the plot area disappears (see image). I have fiddled with the alignment of the x-axes text as thought there may not be enough room but haven't found a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks and code below

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG5Q8.jpg

```
data1 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T)
data1
         Date OMI.Daily.Mean.AOD.500nm
31/07/2018                     0.24
01/08/2018                     0.33
02/08/2018                     0.30
03/08/2018                     0.31
04/08/2018                     0.38
05/08/2018                     0.24
06/08/2018                     0.38
07/08/2018                     0.31
08/08/2018                     0.24
09/08/2018                     0.26
10/08/2018                     0.20
11/08/2018                     0.19
12/08/2018                     0.23
13/08/2018                     0.28
14/08/2018                     0.24
15/08/2018                     0.19
16/08/2018                     0.25
17/08/2018                     0.25
18/08/2018                     0.24
19/08/2018                     0.26
20/08/2018                     0.26
21/08/2018                       NA
22/08/2018                     0.24
23/08/2018                     0.28
24/08/2018                     0.24
25/08/2018                     0.31
26/08/2018                     0.20
27/08/2018                     0.29
28/08/2018                     0.24
29/08/2018                     0.31
30/08/2018                     0.31
31/08/2018                     0.25


library(ggplot)
library(scales)
data1$Date <- as.Date(data1$Date, format = "%m/%d")

ggplot(data1, aes(Date, OMI.Daily.Mean.AOD.500nm)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "Date",y = "OMI Daily Mean AOD (500nm)") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("day"), labels = date_format("%m/%d")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

Comment: hi matthew - to reproduce this problem, can you share which libraries you are using and sample of data1?

Comment: Did you verify that the date conversion was correct?  Your date format is in day/month/year yet `as.Date(data1$Date, format = "%m/%d")` is in month/day.  Change this to correct order "%d/%m"  and it will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick!